# How to open server log details in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to open server log details in IDEA? While starting server there is RUN tool window and "deployment" and "output" windows inside it. How to open server log?

Comment: Did you [enable it](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/7282/20121011154144.png)?

Comment: yep I have added log file like on your image but where it must be displayed in idea?

Comment: all great. Did you know hot to set up level of logging on JBoss?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logs are [configured](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/7282/20121011154144.png) in the Run/Debug configuration. Logging level can be changed according to the [JBoss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html).